# How to count all previous 'li' element width on hover?

Tags: jquery, hover, width

I have list and I'm trying to write jQuery code to count previous li width than I hover on some element. For example if I hover third element I need to get first + second elements width.

```
<ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
    <li>Fourth</li>
</ul>
```

Code at the moment:

```
jQuery('ul li').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).hover(function () {
        jQuery(this).prevAll().width();
    });
});
```

But I get only one previous element width. Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want sum of width:

```
jQuery('ul li').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).hover(function () {
        var prevWidth = 0
        jQuery(this).prevAll().each(function(){prevWidth  += $(this).width();});
        alert(prevWidth );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('ul li').on('mouseenter', function () {
    var width = 0;
    jQuery(this).prevAll().each(function() {
        widht = width + $(this).width();
    });
    console.log(width);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
jQuery(this).prevAll().each(function(){
  $(this).width();
});
```